# SQLITE: Removing records by RowID

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to delete the last 1000 records in my sqlite DB.
The following statement executes with no errors, but deletes (affects) all records.

I use the following SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM LOGS WHERE (SELECT ROWID FROM LOGS ORDER  BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1000)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the sub-query return the last 1000 records

```
SELECT ROWID FROM LOGS ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1000
```

If it returns the correct result, could you try the below query. I added `ROWID IN` in the WHERE clause

```
DELETE FROM LOGS WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM LOGS ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1000)
```